# ReactJS: execute code after .map() statement with ajax call in it is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm stuck at a problem with my twitch tv api app for freecodecamp.

I have a .map() statement with an ajax call in it. And I push the data I get from the call into an array.

I want to set the state of the app to the array after the whole .map() loop is finished but somehow the Array is always empty when I access it outside of .map()

Here is the code I tried.

```
getData() {
  let tempArray= [];
  let self = this;
  STREAMER.map(function(streamer, i) {
    $.ajax({
      url: URL + streamer,
      success: (data) => {
        tempArray.push(data);
      },
      dataType: "jsonp"
    })
  });
  this.setState({data: tempArray});
}
```

I got the feeling that the problem is that the ajax call is asynchronous obv. But I thought since I call the this.setState() method outside of the .map() loop which should be synchronous everything should be fine but isn't.

The Ajax call isn't the problem btw. If I log the data inside of the success method everything is exactly how I like it.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use your `.map()` call to return the promises from all the `$.ajax()` calls. You can then use `$.when()` to wait for them to complete:

```
getData() {
  let tempArray= [];
  let self = this;
  $.when.apply($, STREAMER.map(function(streamer, i) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: URL + streamer,
      success: (data) => {
        tempArray.push(data);
      },
      dataType: "jsonp"
    })
  }).then(function() {}
    self.setState({data: tempArray});
  });
}
```

The returned promises will be gathered up into an array by `.map()`. The returned array is then passed via `.apply()` into `$.when()`. That'll manage waiting for all the promises, and your `.then()` callback will be invoked when they're all done.

If it's at all possible, I suggest you look into the possibility of doing the iteration work at the server and providing a single HTTP API that processes a group of items and returns an aggregate result. HTTP requests take time, and browsers will only do a limited number of them concurrently. One issue in particular with this approach is that the order of the "temp" array will not necessarily match the order of the original array. That is, when the process is done, `tempArray[2]` may or may not contain the result from the ajax call for `STREAMER[2]`.  There's no guarantee that the HTTP requests will complete in the order that they were issued; in fact if you're doing more than a few, then it's very very likely that they'll complete out of order.

Comment: Oh the thing that the http requests may be out of order actually fcks up my whole design pattern :D so I should maybe think about designing my whole app different. But thanks anyway for your answer

Unfortunatly I'm not in charge of the api design of twitch ;)

Comment: @rasmus1610 well you could fix things up by pushing not just the response data, but also the original index value. Then you could make a pass over the result array and re-order it.

Comment: I'm thinking of making the ajax call on the basis of the single item I want to display for the individual streamer. But this has some issues when I want to filter the list of streamers for example.

Answer (score 0):

**SIMPLE SOLUTION**

The `setState()` function should be called inside the success callback of async ajax request.

```
getData() {
  let tempArray= [];
  let self = this;
  STREAMER.map(function(streamer, i) {
    $.ajax({
      url: URL + streamer,
      success: (data) => {
        tempArray.push(data);
        if(i === STREAMER.length - 1) {
          self.setState({data: tempArray});
        }
      },
      dataType: "jsonp"
    })
  });
}
```

**USE PROMISE**

When all ajax requests are successful, resolve the `Promise` and `setState` inside `resolve()`.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the last ajax call will actually be the last one to finish.

Comment: The code changed was as per push implementation. setState will get called after all the ajaxRequests are successful.

Comment: It'll get called when the callback corresponding to the last element in the original array is invoked, at the conclusion of that particular HTTP request. At that time, one or more of the other HTTP requests may not yet have finished. You're right however that that also means that the order of responses in the "temp" array will not necessarily correspond with the order of the original array.

Comment: `setState will get called after all the ajaxRequests are successful`. I think Pointy is correct. setState will get called when all the ajaxRequests *initiated* and at least one has successfully completed.